# sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 doesnt find interface?

Tags: wireless, virtualbox

100% linux newbie here, sorry for all the dumbness.

I'm trying to recover a router password using Reaver Pro.
I'm using Oracle VM Virtual Box to run it.

Everything goes along with the tutorials but when I use `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` it doesn't "find" the interface to monitor.
I mean there is nothing under the words

```
INTERFACE   CHIPSET   DRIVER
```

Also, `iwconfig` only finds `eth0` and `eth1`, no `wlan0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an OS in VirtualBox, almost everything is sandboxed/virtualized. In other words, VirtualBox doesn't use your actual, physical hardware interfaces, but rather sets up its own network interface that is connected to your internet. Therefore, you can't run airmon-ng in VirtualBox. You instead need to run it as a Live CD or have a separate partition for this.